# Error creating crm client msi

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to create an msi for "silent" installs in my organisation.  Here's my command (run as a bat)...

```
cd "C:\CRM\Client Installs\32\Extract"
Setupclient /Q /A /targetdir "C:\CRM\Client Installs\32\Redist" /i "SilentConfig.xml" /LV "C:\CRMClientInstall.log"
```

It chugs along for a few seconds but the log file says (amongst other things)

Administrative image created failed with error 124.

The log file can be found on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/y4tZb1X4).

Any clues?  I'm admin on the machine that's running this.  I've also tried right-click run as admin on a bat file that contains the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I changed the targetdir to be nowhere near the extracted files.  I must have had a locked file somewhere.